# Create new schema, table and insert data in same EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql, insert, schema, plpgsql, execute

I am using PostgreSQL server 9.0.4, I am trying to
1. Create a new schema,
2. Create a table under that schema, and 
3. Insert data in that table,
In the same EXECUTE and its failing. If I try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.test( ) 
    RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$BODY$  
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA test; CREATE TABLE test.t (id integer ); 
INSERT INTO test.t (id) VALUES (0);';
END;
$BODY$;

select pg_temp.test( );
```

I get a failure with the following error.

```
ERROR:  schema "test" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t; CREATE TABLE test.t (id integer ); INSERT INTO test.t (id...
                                                             ^
```

However, the same thing works if use two EXECUTEs in the same transaction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.test( ) 
    RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$BODY$  
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA test; CREATE TABLE test.t (id integer );';
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test.t (id) VALUES (0);';
END;
$BODY$;
```

Unable to understand the difference between the two. Will appreciate if someone can help me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craig's answer is pretty close. I got some more details in answer to my post in postgresql mailing list. See [this](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-CREATE-SCHEMA-and-INSERT-data-in-table-in-that-schema-in-same-EXECUTE-td5769135.html)

To summarize,

1. All sub-statements, in the string to be executed, are parsed before executing any of them. Hence, the parse of INSERT fails as the schema does not exist at that point.
2. CREATE TABLE, being a utility statement is not parsed rigorously and works fine. However, this behavior is implementation specific and might change from release to release.

Further,

> trying to 
>   EXECUTE multiple statements in one query string is something best 
>   avoided, especially if any of them are DDL

Answer (score 3):

You're incorrectly equating multi-statements to transactions.

*The entire function runs inside a single transaction*. Whatever you do is in one transaction. There is no option to autonomously commit or roll back inside a PL/PgSQL function (in Pg 9.3 or older, anyway, if you're reading this and on a newer version, check).

Multi-statements aren't generally a good idea. Doubly so if they include DDL, because at parse time the earlier statements haven't been executed yet.

Just use two `EXECUTE` statements. There is no benefit to using a multi-statement here.

(BTW, you're on PostgreSQL 9.0.4. Upgrade urgently, there are some major bug fixes and [a critical security fix](http://www.postgresql.org/support/security/faq/2013-04-04/) for your version. Upgrading to 9.0.13 is safe, see the [version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot. But, I still am not clear as to why I did not get a 'schema does not exist' for the create table statement. If the create schema statement had not been executed, it should report an error for create table as well.

Comment: @VibhutiNataraj I couldn't tell you that one without digging in the sources, and I'm afraid I don't have time for that right now. Multi-statements have all sorts of fun issues, and I'd suggest avoiding them entirely.

Answer (score -1):

you have to separate it to run,
on a single line does not commit therefore creates no scheme
solution from my point of view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.test( ) 
    RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$BODY$  
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA test'; 
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE test.t (id integer )'; 
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test.t (id) VALUES (0);';
END;
$BODY$;
select pg_temp.test( );
```

Comment: The explanation is not quite right, inside a function you will always be on the same transaction, so there is no commit, even between two commits.

Comment: @MatheusOl ... between two *statements*, rather.

Comment: @CraigRinger: that's right, I meant *two statements* not *two commits* (I don't know how to edit it now)

Comment: @MatheusOl Probably better to delete the answer in this case.